# Can I set a bash script variable to the output of a command and to all lowercase purely with bash parameter expansion?

Tags: bash

I want to set a bash variable to the output of a command and ensure it is all lowercase. I want to keep my code as clean as possible and not pipe output anywhere.

This is what I had before:

```
host=$(hostname -s | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```

Instead I am now using two definitions (being *slightly* shorter):

```
host=$(hostname -s); host=${host,,}
```

but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it in just one definition for host without piping to tr (or anything else). Can the second line be combined any further?

**Edit:** This is exactly why I should copy/paste my code. I did in fact have `'[:upper:]'` and `'[:lower:]'` in my script but typed it incorrectly.

Comment: I think, it isn't possible. But whats bad bout using 2 definitions?

Comment: @Wiimm it's really a matter of keeping a single definition to improve readability. I think the second, shorter version is just about the same amount of readable so I'm not really seeing an advantage. I thought if I could have it happening in one fell swoop, it'd make it easier. I suppose I should be relying on good comments, anyway.

Comment: `host=$(hostname -s | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])` is bad because the `tr` command will get messed up if it is run in a directory  that contains a file whose name is a single character `:`, `e`, `l`, `o`, `p`, `r`, `u`, or `w`.  `host=$(hostname -s | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')` is good.  See the "Ranges" section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for details of why the quotes are necessary.

Comment: I'd argue that trying to combine things further is actively a bad idea for error-handling purposes. With two commands, the first one has a distinct exit status that can be acted on; combine the second always-successful command in and you can lose that -- much akin to how `local result=$(someCommand)` always reports true because `local` succeeds, even if `someCommand` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Bash 4.0 (released in 2009) you can declare `host` so the conversion to lowercase is done automatically on assignment:

```
declare -l host
host=$(hostname -s)
```

If the code is in a function then it's best to localize variables whenever possible, so

```
local -l host
host=$(hostname -s)
```

is only very slightly longer than code that doesn't lowercase the hostname.

It is possible to do the declaration and assignment at the same time

```
declare -l host=$(hostname -s)  # BAD CODE
```

but [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will correctly complain that this masks the exit status of `hostname`, so you can't detect or handle an error.

In this particular case the declaration and assignment can be safely done at the same time if you use the Bash built-in `HOSTNAME` variable instead of the external `hostname` command:

```
declare -l host=${HOSTNAME%%.*}
```

Comment: Note that `declare` implies `local` by default.

Comment: This is fantastic @pjh, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. You make a good point about not being able to properly handle any errors, however so I think I'll include one line for all those variables that need to stay lowercase.